# reverse the value of form field in Django

Tags: django, forms, create-view

I have a model named Ticket

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ...
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

When I using CreateView to create the ticket, how can I reverse the order of 'color' field?  like the newest color is on the top.

Comment: add your forms.py

Comment: In your Color model add [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#ordering) in `class Meta`

Comment: Thanks Shafikur and Vaibhav!! Add Meta to models is very helpful.